# In how many different ways is it possible to distribute these $3n$ books?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Problem**: There $3n$ different books. In how many different ways is it possible to distribute these $3n$ books among $3$ people such that the number of books $1st$ person gets, the number of books $2nd$ gets and the number of books $3rd$ person gets form an arithmetic sequence?

**Attempted Solution**: Let the number of books $1st$, $2nd$ and $3rd$ person receives be $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ respectively. If they are in a arithmetic progression let $d$ be difference of the progression. Then, we have that

  \begin{align} a_2=a_1+d \\ a_3=a_1+2d \\a_1+a_2+a_3=3n \tag{5} \end{align}

 So, we get that $a_1+d=n$. Consequently, $a_2=n$. But I can't go any further. Please, provide a complete solution.

Comment: A good start! So this means $a_1 = n-d$, $a_2=n$, and $a_3=n+d$. Now you have to see in how many ways you can do this where $d$ ranges from $0$ to $n$. So you get a summation of all those different $d$ cases. So, for a specific $d$, how many possibilities are there? I am not giving a complete solution, you try it.

Comment: So your sequence must be $\{n-d,n,n+d\}$ for some $d$, yes?  Well, what can $d$ be?  Presumably I can't give any person a negative number of books...

Comment: OK, so much for trying to help the OP get this him/herself ...

Answer (score 1):

Well:
$$3n=3a_1+2d+d=3a_1+3d\implies n=a_1+d$$
Therefore there are $d$ can have any integer value ranging from $0$ to $n$. We have
$$\sum_{d=0}^{n}{3n\choose n-d}{2n+d\choose n}$$
different progressions (choose $a_1=n-d$ books out of $3n$ books then choose $a_2=a_1+d=n$ books from the remaining $3n-(n-2)=2n+d$. The remaining $n+d$ form the last stack). You now have $3$ stacks of books and $3$ people. You can distribute those stacks in $3!=6$ different ways. Therefore the answer should be:
$$6\sum_{d=0}^{n}{3n\choose n-d}{2n+d\choose n}$$

Comment: $n-d<3n and n<2n+d$ So, {n-d\choose 3n}{n\choose2n+d} doesn't make sense

Comment: $n−d<3n$ and $n<2n+d$. So, what you have written doesn't make any sense.

Comment: oops, I need to reverse them